# Specifying Field Types Indexing from Logstash to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have successfully ingested data using the XML filter plugin from Logstash to Elasticsearch, however all the field types are of the type "text."

Is there a way to manually or automatically specify the correct type?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is specify a [mapping template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/indices-templates.html).

```
PUT _template/template_1
{
  "index_patterns": ["te*", "bar*"],
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "type1": {
      "_source": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "properties": {
        "host_name": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "created_at": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z YYYY"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Change the settings to match your needs such as listing the properties to map what you want them to map to.

Setting **index_patterns** is especially important because it tells elastic how to apply this template. You can set an array of index patterns and can use * as appropriate for wildcards.  i.e logstash's default is to rotate by date. They will look like `logstash-2018.04.23` so your pattern could be `logstash-*` and any that match the pattern will receive the template.

If you want to match based on some pattern, then you can use [dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/dynamic-templates.html).

**Edit:** Adding a little update here, if you want logstash to apply the template for you, here is a link to the [settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-template) you'll want to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following technique good for my use:

Logstash would filter the data and change a field from the default - text to whatever form you want. The documentation would be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html). The example given in the documentation is:

```
filter {
  mutate {
    convert => { "fieldname" => "integer" }
  }
}
```

This you add in the **/etc/logstash/conf.d/02-...** file in the body part. I believe the downside of this practice is that from my understanding it is less recommended to alter data entering the ES.

After you do this you will probably get the [this problem](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/trying-to-grok-a-field-from-string-to-int/78736/6). If you have this problem and your DB is a test DB that you can erase all old data just DELETE the index until now that there would not be a conflict (for example you have a field that was until now text and now it is received as date there would be a conflict between old and new data). If you can't just erase the old data then read into the answer in the link I linked.

Comment: If index_patterns matches the pattern of your rotating index, then the mapping will be created on index creation.  i.e if you use logstash's default and rotate by date they will look like `logstash-2018.04.23` so your pattern could be `logstash-*` and any that match the pattern will receive the template.

Comment: Welcome, was a good call and I tried to clarify that better in my answer.